# Add leading 0 to column of data in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Existing data in data frame has dropped leading zero which is required as a part number. The number stored, needs to be 8 digits long and now they vary based on the removal of the leading 0's

Sorry I am new to Python and this may be built in function in Pandas but I have not found a way to convert this type of formatting.
I have over 2000 part numbers to convert over all

EG:

```
Part No
9069
38661
90705
9070
907
970206
```

Part number needs to be:

```
Part No
00009069
00038661
00090705
00009070
00000907
00970206
```

Comment: Check out `df['Part No'].str.zfill`.

Comment: @Paul Do  you mind marking the correct answer, if it helped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `astype` before using `zfill`, as follows:

`df['Part'].astype(str).str.zfill(8)`